What causes Windows Hello fingerprint and PIN data to be lost?
I own a Lenovo ThinkPad P16 Gen2 running Windows 11 Pro 23H2 with fingerprint sensor.
The account I'm using is local (in case that's important).
On a second disk I have also installed OpenSUSE Leap 15.6.
In the past after a Windows recovery onto a new disk needing multiple attempts I had experienced that the fingerprint authentication had stopped working, but there were too many events that might have caused that, so I did not investigate...
However recently I had switched BIOS to UEFI Secure Boot, and things still worked.
When I tried to boot Linux, there was a message about "secure boot violation" that surprised me, because I thought the recent GRUB is signed for secure boot, but anyway:
I turned off secure boot temporarily, booted Linux where I also had configured multiple fingers to authenticate, and it worked.
However when I booted Window after that, fingerprint authentication did not work any more; actually it wasn't offered any more, and when I tried PIN instead, Windows said after sucessfully checking it (the wrong PIN would not work) that it isn't available at the moment, and that a boot might fix the issue (but it did not; I even tried twice).
What could have happened is this: When restoring Windows after I had built in two disks instead of just one, it is possible that Windows had installed a boot manager on each of the disks, and rather likely they are not identical any more.
When booting Windows from the BIOS boot menu, one bootmanager displayed two Windows installations (during my recovery attempts I had installed a second copy, but now there is only one).
As they wre displayed (in Microsoft manner) as "Windows" and like "Windows on disk 3", I had no idea who's who, so I might have started an "odd" boot manager (boot succeeded, however)...
The "Synaptics Fingerprint Preboot manager" in Windows says my user has three fingers configured (I also had configured a few fingers for a different user...), however...!!!
Thus my questions:

What causes the failure to authenticate using Windows Hello PIN or fingerprints? Is it related to Secure Boot, or is it related when another OS also uses fingerprint authentication? Or is it something completely different?
Which commands exist to examine the current status of PINs and fingerprints (I don't use the camera) in Windows 11 (troubleshooting Windows Hello)?
Specifically I feel worried: If I make a full backup of my Windows partition (e.g. using Acronis True Image), and I will have to restore it: Will the Hello data be backed-up and restored properly, too, or does it reside in the TPM where it cannot be backed up (but overwritten easily (as it seems))?

Digging into it
While waiting for insights, I worked myself deeper into it:
The error code I get is 0xd000a002, and What Is the Ngc Folder in Windows 10? (How to Fix Hello PIN Error 0xd000a002 on Windows PC is a bit more detailed) pointed me to C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\NGC.
Examining that I see that some unnamed user (i.e. I see a SID only) has
read and execute rights on the C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles folder, but not my account (I tried to inspect the contents):

The article cited suggests to delete a file inside, but I would like to inspect what's there first.
When eventually arriving there, I see no AppData subfolder...
So my suspect is that my user lost the rights to access the folder where Hello data is being stored.
Another article named Windows 10: Resetting the Windows Hello Biometrics suggests that the data is stored in C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase, but I could not locate the file while the service is running.
Towards an Answer
As the question was closed, I cannot provide an answer for it, so I'm collecting the insights here for the moment:
From What's new in Windows 10 for developers, build 10586 I learned that "NGC" stands for "Next Generation Credentials", and from Windows 11 Hello won't recognize me I got the paths C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc and C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase.
In addition there is a "Credential Store", which is located in %SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials.
When trying to recover my unbootable Windows I had installed a new one in a separate partition (D:).
Actually I did it more than once as the first version was also unable to boot...
As a result I had D:\Windows and D:\Windows.old.
So after my C:\Windows would boot I had reformatted D: to use the space in a more reasonable way.
As it seems now the fingerprints set after having booted the Windows on C: were stored in D:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\NGC for reasons probably only Microsoft knows (I had tried to locate a corresponding setting in the registry, but failed to find it).
Also recovering the lost D: is not an option unless the fingerprints can be migrated to C.
So I chose (in lack of real alternatives) to re-register the PINs and fingerprints:

First I removed "existing" fingerprints and PIN for my user
Next I re-added a PIN and fingerprints
After verifying I cross-checked that no new file was created on D:

As from now on it worked, I conclude that the formatting of D: destroyed the NGC data (PIN and fingerprints, not related to Secure Boot), but Windows was not smart enough to fully understand.
One command to inspect some NGC data is certutil, e.g. -csp NGC -key -v.
However the certificate structure is rather complex.
I'm not quite sure whether Hello data from NGC can be restored to a new computer (or even the same computer when the TPM had been reset), but my guess is that a backup an restore of all files (except temporary files, maybe) will also backup and restore Windows Hello data.
With the documentation available I could not find out more details.

Wow, two close votes, but not a single comment why?! Did Microsoft buy in already?

I didn't vote, but you could improve your question by focusing on a single issue.

"Synaptics Fingerprint Preboot manager" is Lenovo-specific software, so it can be hard to say exactly. It looks like it stores info in either the BIOS settings or its own boot manager on disk, then passes that info on to Windows where the app is installed. There's not much information about whether it cares what disk/OS is getting loaded. It does look like you might need to reconfigure the fingerprints after a Windows restore/reset, but it may depend on some very specific factors about the backup software you use. I would ask Lenovo for their recommendations there

I voted to close this question as it needs to be focused on a single problem. If your going to make comments like this”did Microsoft buy in already”, I won’t even return, so let’s not soil the water with comments like that. It hasn’t been necessary for OEM fingerprinting software since the release of Windows 10 due to Windows Hello. Your hardware definitely doesn’t require any OEM software for your fingerprint scanner to be functional

I think once it is explained how or why the data is lost, it's also clear where they are stored and whether they are backed up with the disk. OK, I don't know whether the Synaptics preboot fingerprints are identical to the Windows Hello fingerprints, but AFAIR I did not configure any with the Synaptics app (nor in BIOS), so they may be the same as Windows Hello should use (I guess). Also I think this is a highly interesting question.

@U.Windl first, have you already tried just creating a new pin/fingerprint in Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options > Add a PIN? That would normally reset the NGC content on its own. If that's where you get the error in your edit, then just follow the steps to clear it manually (enable view hidden files to see the appdata folder)

@Cpt.Whale I have reasons to believe that it would not work (at the moment), but that would answer none of my questions.

In order to inspect what’s in the folder you have to grant your user access to the folder. I wouldn’t read too much into the SID with access to the folder. I haven’t decoded the SID but suspect it’s simply a service account (or likely the Nvidia account from GeForce Experience or something similar)

I strongly object this question being closed, because: Once it is known where the fingerprints are stored, one would be able to examine the status of the fingerprints, and it would also answer the question whether they can be backed up and restored. - The requirement to split the question is just ridiculous IMHO.

The NGC content is encrypted using your TPM plus pin or biometric - you can't just read it like a text file. You can backup/restore it as long as the local device config (TPM etc) is the same. It sounds like your restore process changed some part of your config to make it invalid. You say "there were too many events that might have caused that", so I'm not sure what you expect
